# Naudio 'NoDriver calling acmFormatSuggest' error on wav exported with imovie

Tags: c#, wav, naudio, imovie

I am trying to convert a .wav to an .mp3 file.
My code usually works but now I have gotten a .wav file that was exported with Imovie and I get the error 'NoDriver calling acmFormatSuggest'.

The internet suggest my machine is missing a codec.
But if I run the file, my machine is able to play the file with standard windows media player, so I guess it is on my machine.

When I put the file into https://www.metadata2go.com/ I can see that the problematic file has the codec pcm_s24le with a sample rate of 48000.

When I create a file with the same codec pcm_s24le but with a sample rate of 44100 the code does not trigger this error. So the problem seems to lie in the combination codec - sample rate.

[Naudio's github page](https://github.com/naudio/NAudio) refers to [this page](https://markheath.net/post/nodriver-calling-acmformatsuggest) with guides to fix the error.
it says under option 5 (i'm only playing back a wav file in my example)

> What you need to do is search the web for an ACM codec that can decode
> the format you are using. Unfortunately this is not always a simple
> process,

It does unfortunately not provide any help on how or where to find these codecs. And, as I'm able to playback the file and the same codec with a different sample rate works fine, I'm also not sure this is the actual problem.

My code runs on a Windows 11 pro v21H2.

The following basic code (this is not my conversion code) throws the error

```
var outputDevice = new WaveOutEvent();
var audioFile = new AudioFileReader(path);
outputDevice.Init(audioFile);
outputDevice.Play();
```

Opening up the wav file and saving it with a different sample rate seems to solve the problem, but that is manual labor I would rather do without, since there are potentially a lot of files to convert in my case.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Would it be acceptable to add some code to resample the .WAV files?  It looks like Naudio has components to do the resampling, as noted on this page:  [How to Resample Audio with NAudio](https://markheath.net/post/how-to-resample-audio-with-naudio).

Comment: @SamGoldberg I think the solution is acceptable from an automation standpoint. I need to find the time to test this. In the meantime, if you post it as an answer you can have the bounty :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like Naudio has components to do the resampling of .WAV files, as noted on this page: [How to Resample Audio with NAudio](https://markheath.net/post/how-to-resample-audio-with-naudio).